# How to predict MySQL tipping points?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I work on a big web application that uses a MySQL 5.0 database with InnoDB tables. Twice over the last couple of months, we have experienced the following scenario:

1. The database server runs fine for weeks, with low load and few slow queries.
2. A frequently-executed query that previously ran quickly will suddenly start running very slowly.
3. Database load spikes and the site hangs.

The solution in both cases was to find the slow query in the slow query log and create a new index on the table to speed it up. After applying the index, database performance returned to normal.

What's most frustrating is that, in both cases, we had no warning about the impending doom; all of our monitoring systems (e.g., graphs of system load, CPU usage, query execution rates, slow queries) told us that the database server was in good health.

Question #1: **How can we predict these kinds of tipping points or avoid them altogether?**

One thing we are not doing with any regularity is running OPTIMIZE TABLE or ANALYZE TABLE. We've had a hard time finding a good rule of thumb about how often (if ever) to manually do these things. (Since these commands LOCK tables, we don't want to run them indiscriminately.) Do these scenarios sound like the result of unoptimized tables?

Question #2: **Should we be manually running OPTIMIZE or ANALYZE? If so, how often?**

More details about the app: database usage pattern is approximately 95% reads, 5% writes; database executes around 300 queries/second; the table used in the slow queries was the same in both cases, and has hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 7):

The MySQL Performance Blog is a fantastic resource. Namely, [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/) post covers the basics of properly tuning InnoDB-specific parameters.

I've also found that the PDF version of the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/#refman) to be essential. [Chapter 7 covers general optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html), and [section 7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-the-server.html) covers server-specific optimizations you can toy with.

From the sound of your server, the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) may be of IMMENSE value to you.

The reference manual also gives you some great detail concerning slow queries, caches, query optimization, and even disk seek analysis with indexes.

It may be worth your time to look into multi-master replication, allowing you to lock one server entirely and run OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE, without taking a performance hit (as 95% of your queries are reads, the other server could manage the writes just fine).

Section 12.5.2.5 covers OPTIMIZE TABLE in detail, and 12.5.2.1 covers ANALYZE TABLE in detail.

Update for your edits/emphasis:

**Question #2** is easy to answer. From the reference manual:

OPTIMIZE:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE should be used if you have deleted a large part of a table or if you have made many changes to a table with variable-length rows. [...] You can use OPTIMIZE TABLE to reclaim the unused space and to defragment the data table.

And ANALYZE:

> ANALYZE TABLE analyzes and stores the key distribution for a table. [...] MySQL uses the stored key distribution to decide the order in which tables should be joined when you perform a join on something other than a constant. In addition, key distributions can be used when deciding which indexes to use for a specific table within a query.

OPTIMIZE is good to run when you have the free time. MySQL optimizes well around deleted rows, but if you go and delete 20GB of data from a table, it *may* be a good idea to run this. It is definitely not required for good performance in most cases.

ANALYZE is much more critical. As noted, having the needed table data available to MySQL (provided with ANALYZE) is very important when it comes to pretty much *any query*. It is something that should be run on a common basis.

**Question #1** is a bit more of a trick. I would watch the server very carefully when this happens, namely disk I/O. My bet would be that your server is thrashing either your swap or the (InnoDB) caches. In either case, it may be query, tuning, or load related. Unoptimized tables could cause this. As mentioned, running ANALYZE can immensely help performance, and will likely help out too.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any good way of predicting MySQL "tipping points" -- and I've run into a few.

Having said that, I've found tipping points are related to table size. But not merely raw table size, rather how big the "area of interest" is to a query. For example, in a table of over 3 million rows and about 40 columns, about three-quarters integers, most queries that would easily select a portion of them based on indices are fast. However, when one value in a query on one indexed column means two-thirds of the rows are now "interesting", the query is now about 5-times slower than normal. Lesson: try to arrange your data so such a scan isn't necessary.

However, such behaviour now gives you a size to look for. This size will be heavily dependant on your server setup, the MySQL server variables and the table's schema and data.

Similarly, I've seen reporting queries run in reasonable time (~45 seconds) if the period is two weeks, but take half-an-hour if the period is extended to four weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) that will help you to narrow down the queries you want to optimize.

For time critical queries it sometimes better to keep stable plan by using hints.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a frustrating situation and maybe not the best code review process and development environment.

Whenever you add a new query to your code you need to check that it has the appropriate indexes ready and add those with the code release.

If you don't do that your second option is to constantly monitor the slow query log and then go beat the developers; I mean go add the index.

There's an option to enable logging of queries that didn't use an index which would be useful to you.

If there are some queries that "works and stops working" (but are "using and index") then it's likely that the query wasn't very good in the first place (low cardinality in the index; inefficient join; ...) and the first rule of evaluating the query carefully when it's added would apply.

For question #2 - On InnoDB "analyze table" is basically free to run, so if you have bad join performance it doesn't hurt to run it.  Unless the balance of the keys in the table are changing a lot it's unlikely to help though.   It almost always comes down to bad queries.  "optimize table" rebuilds the InnoDB table; in my experience it's relatively rare that it helps enough to be worth the hassle of having the table unavailable for the duration (or doing the master-master failover stuff while it's running).